# Await future/coroutine inside event loop; outside coroutine

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have some code with this structure:

```
def my_callback():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(my_coroutine_2())

async def my_coroutine_2():
    return await my_stuff.some_future

async def my_coroutine():
    not_my_code.library_function(my_callback)
```

Inside `my_callback`, which the `library_function` calls, I need to access and run coroutine code.

However, `run_until_complete` produces an error: `Event loop already running!`.

**Is it possible to accomplish what's described above?**

That is to say, is there an ordinary function call which will cause the event loop to pause whatever coroutine is currently executing (i.e. the caller of `loop.run_until_complete()`), and continue executing other coroutines (including the one passed to `run_until_complete()`) until the requested coroutine is finished, in which case the ordinary function un-blocks?

I've thought that maybe threads could help, but as I understand it, all coroutines have to belong to the same thread.

How do I do this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the external library is thread-safe, you can invoke its function off-thread using [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor). While waiting for the function to finish, the current coroutine will be blocked, but the event loop will keep running.

When the your callback is invoked from another thread, it can use [`run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) to submit the coroutine to the (still fully functional) event loop, and report the result back to the library:

```
async def my_coroutine():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, not_my_code.library_function,
                               lambda: my_callback(loop))

def my_callback(loop):
    return asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(my_coroutine_2(), loop)
```

Comment: Well, that does answer the question as asked! Unfortunately in the interest of simplifying the example, I changed what turned out to be an important detail: It's actually the external library that starts the loop and calls library_function; so I don't have the option to change its call style.

So your answer is correct, but doesn't help me! I'll accept it nonetheless.

Comment: @trbabb Is the stuff your coroutines need to do in any way related to the coroutines run by the library? In other words, would it be a problem if the two ran in different and unrelated event loops?

Comment: — my coroutine awaits coroutines/futures spawned in the library's loop.

Comment: @trbabb Now that's quite a pickle. To summarize: you have a library that's implemented using asyncio, that insists on running the event loop on its own inside sync code, and from within the event loop it runs it calls a *sync* callback function and expects a response? And inside your sync callback you need to await other tasks spawned by the library? If so, I'm afraid asyncio doesn't provide a way to do that because it explicitly disallows nesting the event loop, and you can't use multiple event loops. It also sounds like the library is either very badly designed or you're misusing it.

Comment: The library is uwsgi in --asyncio mode. ...No comment on the quality of its design / how much "fun" it's been to work with it. :|

Comment: @trbabb According to [this](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asyncio.html), it should be possible to use greenlets to suspend execution inside a WSGI callable. Have you tried that?